# Регулярное выражение для распознания теннисного счета

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Пишу такой Pattern: `(0|15|30|40):(0|15|30|40)`, но UNIT тест принимает любые числа (например: *20:0*, *100:0*). Должен приниматься счет только с указанными числами (*0, 15, 30, 40)*.

Буду признателен за помощь ибо в регулярных выражениях совсем не силен.

Comment: начало (^) и конец ($) строки поставьте. и просто посмотрите свою регулярку на regexp10.com. там сразу видно что на 20:0 срабатывает на 0:0

Comment: Ваше выражение отлично работает - [`s.matches("(0|15|30|40):(0|15|30|40)"));`](https://ideone.com/WAsROI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно установить начало `^` и конец строки `$`

```
^(0|15|30|40):(0|15|30|40)$
```

Рабочий пример: https://regex101.com/r/PhxrOq/1

Comment: Нужно чтобы было правильно: 0-0(3-5)30:15 или 0-0(6-6)0:0.  А неправильно: 0-0(6-6)20:30.  Пишу такой паттерн:   ^0-0\\((6-6)|([0-5]-[0-5])\\)(0|15|30|40):(0|15|30|40)$     но он ошибку принимает. Что у меня тут не так?

Comment: @НиколайБеляков, а что вы хотите из этой строки вывести вообще?

Comment: @НиколайБеляков, держите https://regex101.com/r/hxyXTE/2

Comment: Ничего не хочу вывести, а хочу реализовать проверку на валидный счет и что это счет именно первого сета.

Comment: Что вам не нравится? https://ideone.com/WAsROI

Comment: Спасибо все работает.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков, если вам помог мой ответ - отметьте его как правильный.